# How to set delay between each repeated iterations in Wow.js animation?

Tags: html, css, transactions, css-transitions

I have created shaking animation using wow.js. I want to pause that shake animation for sometime like 6s and restart the shake animation.How to achieve it? .I have provided snippet of shaking image

```js
// Initialize wow 
new WOW().init();
```

```css
.course-img2 img{
  width:30%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-iteration="1s" data-wow-duration="0.60s" class="wow shake course-img2"> <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" alt="Logo"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wgdLxqrp/

Added an event listener on animation finish which, on finish, changes the value of `data-wow-delay`